# airflow-python Exception wrapper for on_failure notifications

Tags: python, exception, airflow

Im running an airflow dag and that activate a python script,and using on failure callback to send a describe slack msg.

the dag is running(using bashOperator) a test_file.py  that looks like:

```html
test_dag is runing test_runner.py that is falid and the faliure returned as callback to send_slack_msg_on_failure function

**** the test DAG that ******

from dags.utills.dag_helpers import send_slack_msg_on_failure

with DAG(
        'test_msg_dag',
        default_args={
            'retries': 0,
            'on_failure_callback': send_slack_msg_on_failure},
        description='hourly dag that runs hourly etl',
        schedule_interval='0 * * * *',
        start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1, 10, 0),
        catchup=False,
        tags=['test_msg_dag'],
) as dag:
    dag.doc_md = __doc__

    test_dag_msg_task = BashOperator(
        task_id='test_dag_msg_task',

        bash_command='python /home/airflow/gcs/dags/test_runner/test_runner.py A',
    )

    test_dag_msg_task






******** the test_runner.py******


from airflow import AirflowException

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        b = 'h' + 1

    except Exception as e:
        raise AirflowException(e)


******* the 'on_failure_callback': send_slack_msg_on_failure ******

def send_slack_msg_on_failure(context):
    error = context.get("exception") if context.get("exception") else context.get("reason")
    log(error)
```

test_dag has a "on_failure_callback" function.
where in the function im trying to process the error.

in the logs its looks like:

```
[2022-08-02, 14:53:15 IDT] {subprocess.py:74} INFO - Running command: ['bash', '-c', 'python /home/airflow/gcs/dags/test_runner/test_runner.py A']
[2022-08-02, 14:53:15 IDT] {subprocess.py:85} INFO - Output:
[2022-08-02, 14:53:25 IDT] {subprocess.py:89} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2022-08-02, 14:53:25 IDT] {subprocess.py:89} INFO -   File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/test_runner/test_runner.py", line 17, in <module>
[2022-08-02, 14:53:25 IDT] {subprocess.py:89} INFO -     b = 'h' + 1
[2022-08-02, 14:53:25 IDT] {subprocess.py:89} INFO - TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
[2022-08-02, 14:53:25 IDT] {subprocess.py:89} INFO - 
[2022-08-02, 14:53:25 IDT] {subprocess.py:89} INFO - During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[2022-08-02, 14:53:25 IDT] {subprocess.py:89} INFO - 
[2022-08-02, 14:53:25 IDT] {subprocess.py:89} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2022-08-02, 14:53:25 IDT] {subprocess.py:89} INFO -   File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/test_runner/test_runner.py", line 20, in <module>
[2022-08-02, 14:53:25 IDT] {subprocess.py:89} INFO -     raise AirflowException(e)
[2022-08-02, 14:53:25 IDT] {subprocess.py:89} INFO - airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
[2022-08-02, 14:53:25 IDT] {subprocess.py:89} INFO - [2022-08-02, 14:53:25 IDT] {settings.py:340} DEBUG - Disposing DB connection pool (PID 1703)
[2022-08-02, 14:53:26 IDT] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - Command exited with return code 1
[2022-08-02, 14:53:26 IDT] {taskinstance.py:1702} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1330, in _run_raw_task
    self._execute_task_with_callbacks(context)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1457, in _execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, self.task)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1513, in _execute_task
    result = execute_callable(context=context)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash.py", line 187, in execute
    raise AirflowException(
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code 1.
```

the msg that i get from the context is the last line:

```
Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code 1.
```

where what i wanted to print in the msg is

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

or event the traceback

any idea how i can raise the right error msg?

Answer (score 0):

Airflow collect stdout. you can print the exception and exit with sys.exit(1)

```
import sys
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        b = 'h' + 1

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        sys.exit(1)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks oz! , but im getting roughly the same result where the final error that im catching in the on_faliure_callback(from the context) is:
Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code 1.

Comment: @danielverman, can you, please share your DAG code.

Comment: hi @ozs i edit my answer and added the DAG and msg function into the snippet